# My minecraft "Versions" file doesn't contain Version I want?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

I want to create a Minecraft resource pack, so I need standard textures, but the Versions file doesn't contain the Version I want (1.16+). How do I get the textures?

[image]

Answer (score 2):

If the Minecraft version you want is missing from your `.minecraft/versions` folder, the problem is likely that you haven't played that particular version before.

You can easily fix this by opening the Minecraft launcher, then starting the version of Minecraft that you want to get the textures from (in your case, 1.15.2). Once the title screen appears, you can close the game.

The files should now be present at `.minecraft/versions/1.15.2`. You may need to use a third-party program such as WinRAR or 7-Zip to access the textures, as they are contained with a `.jar` file that most operating systems cannot open on their own.

Comment: I did play the Version before many times

Comment: @allb It looks like your `.minecraft` folder is located on the D drive. Are you absolutely sure that the Minecraft Launcher is set to use that folder?

Comment: How do I verify if the Launcher is using the folder?

Comment: @allb It's in the profile settings.

Comment: @Fabian Röling Be more specific please

Comment: @allb Sorry, it's called "installations" now for some reason. You can edit those and choose a "game directory". But if you don't know that, it's probably the default and your "D:" drive folder is not in use at all.